# How to keep document.write() from overwriting my HTML when the script is external and non-editable?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, rss

I am having trouble designing my website because the scripts are using document.write() which overwrites everything that I am trying to create.

I have no way of changing this(as far as I know) since this is a script provided from FeedWind(http://feed.mikle.com/).

FeedWind provides an very neat RSS widget that I can use for my news feed, the only downside is that I do not yet know a way of getting around the document.write() problem.

I am currently using the meteor framework.

I would be extremely happy to recieve some help, thank you!

Here is the script provided to me, all I've edited is the layout just to make it readable.

```
        <!-- start feedwind code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write
            (
                '\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' +
                ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +
                'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>'
            );
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function()
        {
            var params =
            {
            rssmikle_url: "http://www.nrk.no/norge/toppsaker.rss|\
            http://tv2.no/rss/tv2nyhetene-innenriks-siste.xml?_ga=1.56852137.2011408189.1427372857|\
            http://www.smp.no/?widgetName=polarisFeeds&widgetId=6485103&getXmlFeed=true|\
            http://www.rbnett.no/?widgetName=polarisFeeds&widgetId=6485383&getXmlFeed=true|\
            http://www.adressa.no/?widgetName=polarisFeeds&widgetId=3185248&getXmlFeed=true|\
            http://www.tk.no/service/rss|http://www.vg.no/rss/feed/?categories=&keywords=&limit=100&format=rss",
                rssmikle_frame_width: "300",
                rssmikle_frame_height: "400",
                frame_height_by_article: "0",
                rssmikle_target: "_blank",
                rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                rssmikle_font_size: "12",
                rssmikle_border: "on",
                responsive: "off",
                rssmikle_css_url: "",
                text_align: "left",
                text_align2: "left",
                corner: "off",
                scrollbar: "on",
                autoscroll: "on",
                scrolldirection: "up",
                scrollstep: "3",
                mcspeed: "20",
                sort: "New",
                rssmikle_title: "on",
                rssmikle_title_sentence: "",
                ssmikle_title_link: "",
                rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",
                rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",
                rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",
                rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",
                rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",
                rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",
                rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",
                rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",
                rssmikle_item_description: "on",
                item_link: "on",
                rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",
                rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",
                rssmikle_item_date: "on",
                rssmikle_timezone: "Europe/Oslo",
                datetime_format: "%e.%m.%Y %k:%M:%S",
                item_description_style: "text+tn",
                item_thumbnail: "full",
                item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",
                article_num: "15",
                rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",
                keyword_inc: "taxi;oslo",
                keyword_exc: ""
            };
        feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();
        </script>
            <div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:300px;">
                <a  href="http://feed.mikle.com/"
                    target="_blank"
                    style="color:#CCCCCC;">
                        RSS Feed Widget
                </a>
                <!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.-->
            </div>
        <!-- end feedwind code -->
```

Comment: You can try putting widget in iframe, like in example on their site.
Or you can just write document.write = function () {}; above those scripts adding. But this will affect the whole page and may cause additional problems.

Comment: It worked putting it in an iframe, thank you! :)